# django proxy models more than one Foreign Key Error

Tags: django

My model structure is as follows.

```
class SuperModel(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class child_A(supermodel):
  class Meta:
     proxy = True

class child_B(supermodel):
  class Meta:
     proxy = True

class Reference(models.Model):
  child_a = models.ForeignKey(Child_A, blank=True, null=True)
  child_b = models.ForeignKey(Child_B, blank=True, null=True)
  super_model = models.ForeignKey(Child_C, related_name=supermodel)
```

I have actually 4 child models. I have shown 2 to make the point. I am keeping `super_model`
so I can get to the supermodel without checking all the childs. Only One child will have reference the supermodel. I am getting error that `Reference has more than One Foreign key to Child_B.` while doing `runserver`
Can some one point out the error.

EDIT :super_model as a field in Reference, I have kept so I can access Reference through Reverse Relation from SuperModel.

Comment: what's Child_C ? same as child_B and child_A? ps: you missed an a in Meta for child_B

Comment: Sorry about the a, edited now. Yes all children are same. I want to access Reference model through a method on SuperModel using reverse relationship.

Comment: i don't know why you get the error. anyway, have a look at this https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils/blob/master/README.rst#inheritancemanager it might be useful for you